# How to set html table height and column widths?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to control the height of a table body so that a scrollbar appears when more data than fits in a view is displayed, thead must stay visible.  At the same time I'm trying to control the width of the table columns.

The table height can be controlled by setting 'display: block' in the table body css.  The table body will now be limited by the container height or any height the table body is set to.  This messes up the column widths though.

The column widths can be assured by setting   as desired.  As long as the tbody isn't set to 'display: block' the columns display properly but the tbody is out of control and ignores any height you may have set.

I'm trying to do this to make it possible for the result to be easily chapter 508 compliant for screen reader technology for those with disabilities.   AT this point, I'm planning to convert to jquery.dataTables which puts a view port over top of a table so I can keep the 508 compliance and get the functionality I need.  This seems way over the top for what I'm wanting to accomplish but I can't find a simple way to do it with a native table and basic css.

Test code is as follows:

```
<div id="div1">
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col id='col-1'>
        <col id='col-2'>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>February is a long month that seems like it could go on forever!</td>
            <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>March</td>
            <td>$180</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>April</td>
            <td>$86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>May</td>
            <td>$98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>June</td>
            <td>$29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>$44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>August</td>
            <td>$244</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
#div1 {
height: 100px;
width: 400px;
padding: .5px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
colgroup {
width: 100%;
}
#col-1 {
width:70%;
}
#col-2 {
width:30%;
}
table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: auto;
}
thead {
background-color: #B2DFFF;
}
tbody {
height: 72px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
/* display:block;   This will set column width correctly but it messes up tbody height */
display:block;  /* This will allow height to be set but it messes up columns width */
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Agree with answer, but in future using CSS to style a <ul><li> might be better for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:scroll;` to `#div1` to add scroll beyond a height of 100px.

http://jsfiddle.net/NK378/13/

**EDIT:**

I could not see from your question that you wanted the header in view at all times. To do this, aply the style to the tbody so it doesn't apply to the header.. So the tbody tag has an id of "scroll", and the css for #scroll is:

```
#scroll {
    display:block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width:400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NK378/17/

Comment: Again, same issue, table header scrolls out of view.

Comment: @brian It's not mentioned in your question that I have seen. See the my edited answer for the fix to keep the table header in view anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `display: block` on tables.  They need their default `display: table` in order to function correctly.

You can just set the containing div to scroll when it overflows:

```
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: .5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Added */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NK378/12/)**

---

**UPDATE**

I completely missed the requirement for the thead to not scroll.  One way to achieve this is to nest another table inside the first to separate it from the thead.  You are allowed to place a `<div>` inside a `<td>` so that's how you create the scroll.

```
<div id="div1">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th class="savings">Savings</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="table-body">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>January</td>
                                    <td>$100</td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>February is a long month that seems like it could go on forever!</td>
                                    <td>$80</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>March</td>
                                    <td>$180</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>April</td>
                                    <td>$86</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>May</td>
                                    <td>$98</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>June</td>
                                    <td>$29</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>July</td>
                                    <td>$44</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August</td>
                                    <td>$244</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Some additional styles

```
th:first-child, td:first-child {
    width: 80%;
}

table table td {
    padding: 4px 5px;
}

.table-body {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NK378/20/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, when you make the div scroll you lose the table header.  I know I could make a table header outside the div but then I have to coordinate the header and table behavior.  The only reason I'm trying to solve this is I need to be chapter 508 compliant and a div table is very difficult to assure compliance with.

Comment: At least I haven't found any JavaScript/DIV tables that are 508 compliant.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's 508 compliant to be honest, but I've added one way of doing it through nested tables

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto` to your container div's css.

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmarple/NK378/10/

Comment: This causes the whole table to scroll within the div and loses track of the table header.

Comment: You didn't specify that you wanted a static header in your question!

Comment: A static table header should go without stating, but, whatever.

Comment: How should it? Yes it may be obvious to us why a static table header is desirable but that's not always the case. Please specify that in your question, as you can see I'm not the only person that has assumed that you don't want table headers. **We're answering your questions for free - don't get sarky**

Comment: @brian I'd edit your question to get the relevant answers you want

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just have some considerations:

```
thead {display: table; width: 100%;}
tbody {display: block; overflow: auto;}
tbody tr {display: table; width: 100%;}
td, th {/* should set a width for each td, th*/}
```

This is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/NK378/14/

Comment: This is the solution I have been using.  The issue is that the columns don't line up.  The wider the table or the more columns displayed, the more off kilter the header and body columns get.  If the body has a scrollbar the line up looks acceptable, but if it doesn't have a scrollbar then the lineup is poor.  This is the problem I first started to solve that lead down this tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "display" property to "inline-block" and "max-width", "min-width", "overflow-x", "white-space" like that:
**CSS**

```
tbody td {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;   
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/uYLb4/1/)
Watch the second line in the table.

In the case you want to limit the height of your td:
CSS

```
tbody td {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    max-height: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/dUrjp/1/)